# Configure Spring Boot integrate Keycloak with SSL

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, keycloak

I integrate Spring boot with Keycloak. Keycloak already installed to run on 2 ports: 8080 without ssl and 8443 with ssl.

If I configure Spring boot with keycloak without ssl then It can run as well. Once Spring Boot integrate Keycloak with ssl then I already get errors like below:

[image]

I can use postman to get an access token from keycloak with ssl, no errors. Who know how to integrate Spring boot and Keycloak with ssl please help me up

Comment: I guess that the certificate do not have a valid root CA.

Comment: Please show us you spring boot config. It looks like you did not configure a truststore properly.

Comment: I have the same problem. I created crt.pem and key.pem and used for Keycloak. HTTPS and tokens are okay in Keycloak. Accessing my Spring Boot APIs would result to the same issue. I have imported the crt.pem to JDK cacerts. I verified it and it's there. I use the same JDK to run my Spring Boot. I also tried to create a trustore out of crt pem. I added `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` as arguments to Java when running SB app, the issue is still the same. I haven't resolved it.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL certificate with which runs Keycloak is not in the cacerts file of the JRE your Spring app runs into.

You can look into [that tiny repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/self-signed-certificate-generation) for a script to

- generate a self-signed certificate (if you have not already)
- add this certificate to cacerts

Then, be sure you use that same certificate when running Keycloak. Here are two [configuration options](https://www.keycloak.org/server/enabletls), depending on the kind of certificate you have at hand:

```
https-certificate-file=/path/to/certfile.pem
https-certificate-key-file=/path/to/keyfile.pem
```

```
https-key-store-file=C:/Users/ch4mp/.ssh/self_signed.jks
https-key-store-password=change-me
```

Comment: Yep, OP needs to ensure those certificates are imported to the KC truststore

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. I imported the certificate used by NGINX and the domain, not the certificate of the Keycloak server.